Solving a specific difference equation
Dynamics
I have the following recursive discrete dynamics for $t=1,2,\dots,d$ where we can assume $d>100$ or even $d\to\infty$ if needed.
\begin{align}
x_{1}   =1,\quad \quad 
x_{2}   = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\frac{1}{d}}}{2},\quad \quad 
\forall t=3,\dots,d:~~
x_{t}   =\frac{x_{t-1}+\sqrt{x_{t-1}^{2}-4\beta_{t}}}{2}
\end{align}
where
$
\beta_{t}=\frac{1}{d}\left(\left(t-1\right)2^{-\frac{2t-4}{d}}-\left(t-2\right)2^{-\frac{2t-5}{d}}\right)
$.
Overall, $\beta_t$ are rather small (since $d\ge 100$) and strictly positive. Then, at each iteration the decrease $x_{t-1} - x_t$ is also small.
The iterates behave as plotted below:


The problem

Ideally, we would hope to find a closed-form for $x_t$.
Alternatively, it is also useful for me to prove that $x_{t} - 2x_{t-1}+x_{t-2}>0$, i.e., that $\left(x_{t-1}-x_{t}\right)_{t}$ is monotonically decreasing.
This seems to be the case numerically, but we couldn't prove it. We tried to solve an ODE with a continuous approximation, but that didn't work out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

In the limit $d\to\infty$ the op's difference equation can be transformed into an ordinary differential equation, which can be solved exactly.
We define $\tau=t/d$ and expand
$\beta(\tau) = \beta_{\tau d}$ around $d=\infty$,
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\beta(\tau) = \frac{4^{-\tau}(1-\tau \ln2)}{d} + \mathcal{O}(d^{-2})\,.
\end{align}
Next, we rewrite the $x_t$-recursion in terms of $\tau$, too, and get (with $\delta\tau=1/d$)
\begin{align}\tag{2a}\label{eq:2a}
x(\tau)
&=\frac{x(\tau{-}\delta\tau)+\sqrt{x^2(\tau{-}\delta\tau)-4\beta(\tau)}}{2}\\
\tag{2b}\label{eq:2b}
&=\frac{x(\tau{-}\delta\tau)+\sqrt{x^2(\tau{-}\delta\tau)-4^{1-\tau}(1-\tau \ln2)\,\delta\tau+\mathcal{O}(\delta\tau^2)}}{2}\,,
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\tag{3a}\label{eq:3a}
x'(\tau)&=\lim_{\delta\tau\to 0}\frac{x(\tau)-x(\tau{-}\delta\tau)}{\delta\tau}\\
\tag{3b}\label{eq:3b}
&=-\frac{4^{-\tau}(1-\tau \ln2)}{x(\tau)}\,.
\end{align}
The solution of this ODE with initial condition $x(0)=1$ reads
\begin{align}
\tag{4}\label{eq:4}
x(\tau)=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\ln4}+4^{-\tau}\left(\frac{1}{\ln4}-\tau\right)}\,.
\end{align}
The convexity for $0\leq\tau\leq1$ follows.

This is great! Thank you very much
